# What is the logic behind Putin's nuclear mobilization?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nuclear-weapons

- https://www.cbsnews.com/news/russia-nuclear-weapons-train-video/
- https://nypost.com/2022/10/03/putin-deploys-worlds-largest-submarine-nuclear-convoy/

Putin is mobilizing his strategic nuclear weapons and nuclear submarines. What is the logic?

Suppose that Ukraine recaptures all its lost territories.

How would these nuclear missiles and submarines be able to reverse that?

If he really uses nuclear weapons, how come Russian administration expect to avoid another Nuremberg-like trial?

Comment: "how come Russian administration..." They probably don't plan to travel outside of Russia and some selected countries soon.

Comment: In Douyin, China was shown preparing for the fallout from the nuclear war.

Comment: The logic is that the recently annexed lands are part of Russian territory which is to be protected at any cost.

Comment: Ehh, not my DV but "how come Russian administration expect to avoid another Nuremberg-like trial?" By nuking everyone who tries that, given your premises?

Comment: @Stančikas ""This video of a train is a very good example of Russian strategy of trying to increase the pressure on the West and signal its — maybe not necessarily readiness — but willingness to escalate..." when did that train actually move? Last year? Is that simply file footage used as mis/disinformation? Consider the source.

Comment: Those don't seem confirmed by official US sources as unusual moves https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-biden-armageddon-remark-kirby-ukraine/32072211.html

Comment: @uhoh - A few days ago? As indicated in the article?

Comment: @Obie2.0 the comment I'm replying to has been deleted, so I don't know what "the article" is. I understand the video was posted a few days ago, but factually verifying when it was *actually filmed* i.e. when the train was moved and just what was on it is another matter altogether.

Comment: "an armored personnel carrier with a cannon attached" the source says. May  not be a nuclear weapon

Comment: -1.  The New York Post is a semi-tabloid with questionable accuracy at the best of times.  People are already edgy enough about Putin's saber rattling, without putting up questions of an extremely alarming nature here with apparently no background check whatsoever - no serious sources carry news of significant enhanced Russian nuclear forces at this time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem based on reliable information.

Comment: https://www.reuters.com/world/white-house-says-has-no-indication-russia-is-preparing-use-nuclear-weapons-2022-10-04/ https://www.forbes.com/sites/madelinehalpert/2022/10/09/white-house-sees-no-indication-russia-is-preparing-nuclear-attack-after-bidens-armageddon-warning https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-ato/3580212-us-seeing-no-signs-of-russia-preparing-nuclear-attack-white-house.html Not putting as answer, on purpose, this is not a reasonable Q to be asking here.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no mobilisation** [(source)](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/oct/07/biden-putin-nuclear-threats-tactical-strike-us-response-analysis?CMP=Share_AndroidApp_Other)

> Russia has 2,000 tactical weapons, in very many shapes and sizes for use on land, sea and air. The weapons are not deployed on missiles or aircraft, but kept in bunkers in storage sites dotted around Russia. There are 12 national storage sites, known in Russian military parlance as “Object S”, one of which is in Belgorod, right on the Ukrainian border.

> There are also 34 “base-level” sites, closer to the delivery systems. In a time of crisis, warheads would be moved from national to base-level sites – and up to now western intelligence agencies say **no such movement has been observed**

Sources in the question talk about a train carrying that looks more like conventional weapons (canons) and the submarine carrying nuclear weapon delivering drone left its base in Arctic circle but this is still far and Turkey unlikely to let it into Black Sea. If they plan to strike with underwater drone, what would be the military target? Ukraine has no notable fleet so no large military ports.

These may be just ordinary movements, while if they only plan to detonate a single warhead for the demo, no mobilisation would be necessary.